# reversing byte order in c

Tags: c, memory, bit-manipulation, byte

I got problem solving 'reverseBytes' in cs:app datalab.

i have to make code that returns reversed byte order.

*example : input=0x123456, returns=0x563412*

when i used my code, it can't take a score..

```
int reverseBytes(int x) {
  int mask=0xff;
  int byte1=x>>24;
  int byte2=(x>>16)&mask;
  int byte3=(x>>8)&mask;
  int byte4=x&mask;
  int result=(byte4<<24)|(byte3<<16)|(byte2<<8)|(byte1);

  return result;
}
```

but, when i used other people's code, it takes a score.

```
int reverseBytes(int x) {
  int t2=~(0xff<<24);
  int s1=(0xff<<16)+0xff;
  int s2=0xff<<8;
  int s3=(s2<<16)+s2;
  int temp=(x&s1)<<8|((x&s3)>>8&t2);
  int q1=(0xff<<8)+0xff;
  int q2=q1<<16;
  int temp2=(temp&q1)<<16|((temp&q2)>>16&(~q2));

  return temp2;
}
```

i don't know why my code can't works..
i tested my code and other people's code.
but i can't find difference between my code's result and another code's result.
please help me..

Comment: Have you looked at the result of applying your code to the example data you provided?  It won't be the result you say is expected, but if you print it in hexadecimal form then it should be pretty obvious what's wrong.

Comment: On the other hand, the code you say *does* work will not produce the given example output either.

Comment: Read about [htonl(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/htonl.3.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am not sure about this as OP wants reverse bytes regardless if they are le or be. htonl(3) will do nothing in latter case

Comment: Right shifting a negative value is implementation defined. Use unsigned types and do not rely on `int`/`unsigned` having 32 bits. Use `uint32_t` instead. Left shifting a signed value chainging th sign is undefined behaviour even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following functions swap bytes-strings of whichever length you want. The `swapbytes()` swaps all the bytes contained in the `inp` parameter inside `inp` thus modifying the contents of `inp`. The `swapbytesout()` swaps the contents of the `inp` paramenter inside the `out` parameter, then it doesn't modify the contents of `inp`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void * swapbytes(void *inp, size_t len);
void * swapbytesout(void * inp, void *out, size_t len);

/* This function swaps and modifies the content of inp
 *
 * Returns: a pointer to the output value (inp) */
void * swapbytes(void *inp, size_t len)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned char *in=(unsigned char *)inp,tmp;

    for(i=0;i<len/2;i++) {
        tmp=*(in+i);
        *(in+i)=*(in+len-i-1);
        *(in+len-i-1)=tmp;
    }

    return inp;
}

/* This function doesn't swap and doesn't modify the content
 * of inp, the output is computed on out.
 *
 * Returns: a pointer to the output value (out) */
void * swapbytesout(void *inp, void *out, size_t len)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned char *o=(unsigned char *)out;
    unsigned char *in=(unsigned char *)inp;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
        *(o+len-i-1)=*(in+i);
    }

    return out;
}

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t a0,a1;
    uint64_t b0,b1;

    a0=0x12345678;
    printf("%08X\n",*(uint32_t *)swapbytesout(&a0,&a1,sizeof(a0)));
    printf("%08X %08X\n",a0,a1);

    printf("%08X\n",*(uint32_t *)swapbytes(&a0,sizeof(a0)));
    printf("%08X\n",a0);

    puts("");

    b0=0x123456789ABCDEF0ULL;
    printf("%016"PRIX64"\n",*(uint64_t *)swapbytesout(&b0,&b1,sizeof(b0)));
    printf("%016"PRIX64" %016"PRIX64"\n",b0,b1);

    printf("%016"PRIX64"\n",*(uint64_t *)swapbytes(&b0,sizeof(b0)));
    printf("%016"PRIX64"\n",b0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple right shift to get the byte needed will do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t reverse_bytes(uint32_t bytes)
{
    uint32_t aux = 0;
    uint8_t byte;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 32; i+=8)
    {
        byte = (bytes >> i) & 0xff;
        aux |= byte << (32 - 8 - i);
    }
    return aux;
}
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/kqaqbZ):

```
int main(void) {
    uint32_t input = 0x123456;
    printf("input: 0x%08x\n", input);
    input = reverse_bytes(input);
    printf("input: 0x%08x\n", input);
    return 0;
}
```

prints:

input: 0x00123456

input: 0x56341200

Answer (score 3):

use this:

```
#define reverse_bytes_32(num) ( ((num & 0xFF000000) >> 24) | ((num & 0x00FF0000) >> 8) | ((num & 0x0000FF00) << 8) | ((num & 0x000000FF) << 24) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The shift operator preserves signing.   Try changing "int byte1=x>>24;" to " "int byte1=x>>24&mask;".
Or just switch to using unsigned ints.

Comment: Well, in fact the result of the right shift of a negative number is implementation-defined.  Either arithmetic or logical shift can be provided, or, technically, every such shift could produce the value 42.  The implementation just needs to document its choice.

Comment: With that said, yes, the failure to mask the result of the shift is a good candidate for the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of reversing the byte order for **various number of bytes**.

```c
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string.h> 

void reverse_byte_order(void *data, uint32_t num_bytes) {
    void *dest = malloc(num_bytes);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_bytes; ++i) {
        memcpy(dest + num_bytes - i - 1, data + i, 1);
    }
    memcpy(data, dest, num_bytes);
    free(dest);
}

int main() {
    uint32_t data1 = 0x12345678;
    printf("0x%08x\n", data1);
    reverse_byte_order(&data1, 4);
    printf("0x%08x\n", data1);

    uint32_t data2 = 0xabcdef;
    printf("0x%08x\n", data2);
    reverse_byte_order(&data2, 3);
    printf("0x%08x\n", data2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0x12345678
0x78563412
0xabcdef
0xefcdab
```

This implementation does not require bit shifting or `AND`/`OR` operation. It basically just copy the memory from place to place one by one. It looks more straightforward in my eyes though.